# How to pass string argument to another script in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently working on a plugin and now stuck. Tried searching but had not idea what to look for, help..
I had everything working fine until I decided to use couroutines for delay. I need to pass temp to another script. Look for //ERROR . Thanks
First Script:

```
            void Start()
            {
                skinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent();
                Speakers speakers = new Speakers();
                SwaitTime = speakers.waitTime;
                StalkSpeed = speakers.talkSpeed;

            }

            public void click()
            {

                foreach (Speakers i in speakerList)
                {
                    string[] temp = split(i);

                    //ERROR
                    newLetterCombo = gameObject.AddComponent(); //able to access couroutine in 2nd script but does not pass temp argument like below.
//letterCombo newLetterCombo = new letterCombo(temp); [worked earlier but does not access couroutine, also puts up monobehavior new keyword not allowed]

                    newLetterCombo.switchStarter();

                }

            }
```

Second Script:

```
            public string[] letters;

            public letterCombo(string[] _letters)
            {
                letters = _letters;

            }

            public void switchStarter()
            {
                StartCoroutine(comboswitch());
            }


            private IEnumerator comboswitch()
            {
                foreach (string combo in letters)
                {
                    switch (combo)
                    {
                        case "AA":
                            print("AA");
                            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                            break;
            [/code]
```

Comment: You can just pass the parameter.

Comment: @GunnarB. please explain or correct the line, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call

```
newLetterCombo.switchStarter(temp);
```

And change the other functions to

```
public void switchStarter(string[] temp)
{
    StartCoroutine(comboswitch(temp));
}


private IEnumerator comboswitch(string[] temp)
{
    //...
}
```